# I can't upload a file with CGIHTTPServer

Tags: python, cgi

I'm using the CGIHTTPServer to implement a simple cgi server. I'm trying to upload a file by a form with the post method and the multipart/form-data enctype but I have problems when I recover the value of the fields in the cgi script.

When the script catch the form fields, the value of the file is a MiniFieldStorage with two fields only (key and file name), and I can't recover the content of the file. As the API doc shows, this content is in value field of a StorageField but in the MiniFieldStorage this field isn't exits.

¿How can I recover a StorageField with the content of the file instead a MiniStorageField? ¿There are other method to upload a file using CGIHTTPServer?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Please provide some code example.
Guessing from the text, you should look into the [`cgi` module](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#module-cgi).
Follow the examples, specially the [`cgi.test()`](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.test) function.

> `cgi` — Common Gateway Interface support
>
> Support module for Common Gateway Interface (CGI) scripts.
>
> This module defines a number of utilities for use by CGI scripts written in Python.

Quoting the [`FieldStorage` description](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#using-the-cgi-module) (using the cgi module):

> To get at submitted form data, it’s best to use the `FieldStorage` class. The other classes defined in this module are provided mostly for backward compatibility. Instantiate it exactly once, without arguments. **This reads the form contents from standard input or the environment** (depending on the value of various environment variables set according to the CGI standard). Since it may consume standard input, it should be instantiated only once.